# Is a biometric passport required for layover in the USA?

Tags: usa, passports, layovers

I want to visit Canada, for which, according to my research, I do not require an electronic passport.  However, most flights have a layover in the USA. I know I need an electronic passport to enter the US, do I also need it for layover?

Comment: You always enter the US, even when transiting.

Comment: You do need one to [benefit from the VWP](http://www.dhs.gov/visa-waiver-program-passport-requirements-timeline). Otherwise, you need a visa.

Comment: @Relaxed That's not quite true. If your passport is issued after 26th October 2006, it must be an electronic one to use VWP. However, a passport issued before that date does no have to be electronic. Some countries (e.g., the UK, which is in VWP) issue passports valid for ten years. So there are still people who can enter the USA on VWP without an electronic passport.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know. But as you note yourself, it's already rare and soon to be irrelevant. Anybody who needs the details can follow the link, that's why it's there.

Comment: @Relaxed I, for one, assumed the link was a citation (i.e., "here's the proof, if you don't believe me") and not "by the way, although I said you do need an electronic passport, actually some people don't and you should read this to find out if you're one of those people."

Comment: @DavidRicherby You also assumed I can't read?

Comment: @Relaxed No, I assumed that you were correct, which meant that the situation had changed. That would be significant to me because it would mean I would need a new passport to USA under VWP. I followed the link to see exactly what the situation was, and thereby found that your claim was incorrect.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My claim was precise enough in its context, which is a brief comment *and a link* about a poorly researched question. And since I added that link to the detailed rules myself, it still makes no sense to assume I meant anything else. It's not like it's hidden somewhere deep down on the page…

Comment: @Relaxed Your comment implies, but I think it ought to be stated explicitly, that biometric passports are not required for those entering the USA with a visa.  The premise of the question is therefore not entirely correct.